# Plotting percent change over a specific range?

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to plot the percentage change over X amount of bars.  The problem I'm running into is that it's adding each bar individually, instead of plotting the range of the move.

Ex: percent change of the last 20 bars will equal 10.31%, however, the code will give a value of 11.02%.  I've tried change/range/sum functions, and sum is the only one that's close enough to what I'm looking for

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.  Probably an easy fix, but I'm very novice when it comes to coding.

```
study("My Script", precision=2)

len = input(title='Length', type=input.integer, defval=20)
btc = security("ftx:btcperp", timeframe.period, close)
a = sum((btc-btc[1]) / btc[1] * 100,len)
plot(a, 'btc', color=color.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

Afternoon,

Not sure if the below will help but I use the below to monitor percentage changes from a set period of time and display for a set period.

```
//@version=4
study("Baseline", overlay=false)

baselinetime = input("0000-0200", "Baseline", input.session) //set baseline range
blt = time(timeframe.period, baselinetime)


analysisrange = input("0700-2100", "Analysis Range", input.session) //set analysis range
ar = time(timeframe.period, analysisrange)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if blt
    if not blt[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)

midpoint = (highe_01+lowe_01)/2
inc = (close - midpoint)//change(close, length)
p = (inc/close)*100

plot(ar ? p : na, title="Percentage Change", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
```